# How to strip off certain characters from String text Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I've got a pice of String text as such:

`<![CDATA[<SomeTag>SomeText Here</SomeTag>]]>`

I'd like to strip off the CDATA tag so I just get this:

`<SomeTag>SomeText Here</SomeTag>`

How can I accomplish this in Java using anymethod, preferably regular expressions?

Edit:
What if it weren't CDATA it could be any piece of text, I'd like to extract just this:
`<SomeTag>SomeText Here</SomeTag>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
source.replaceAll("\\<!\\[CDATA\\[","").replaceAll("\\]\\]\\>", "")
```

or

```
source.replaceAll("\\<!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]\\>",""));
```

or with pattern matching

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\<!\\[CDATA\\[|\\]\\]>"); 
    String s = "<![CDATA[<explanation>SomeText Here</explanation>]]>";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s); 
    String extracted = "";

    while (m.find()) { 
       extracted = m.replaceAll("");
    }


        System.out.println(extracted );
```

Comment: What is the wrapping text weren't CDATA what if it were foo or some other arbitary text?

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work

Comment: thanks, i made some changes. please review

Comment: basically if you have a list of things that you want to replace, just add them to the regex

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly

Comment: sure, glad to help :) all the best !